# Bliss point utility doubt

Tags: microeconomics, utility, consumer-theory

Why is the bliss point utility function convex even though it has concave portions to it ?

According to Nicholson and Snyder (authors of Microeconomic theory - Basic principles and extensions) a function has diminishing MRS and is convex only if it is quasi-concave. Accordingly, I checked quasi concavity for the bliss point utility function $U (x, y) = 12x + 16y –x^2 – y^2$, and it showed that the function is quasi concave throughout. This means that the function should be convex throughout, but that is not the case here.

Comment: @denesp Where are you for this one?

Comment: @EconJohn One does not get notifications if tagged in a question where one has no posts. I am also unsure what you mean? I am not the single arbiter of truth.

Comment: @denesp whoops, Didn't know that. In the past you seemed to be knowledgeable on bliss points i.e. https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/13782/utility-function-used-to-indicate-bliss-point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quasi-concave utility functions represent convex preferences. But that preferences are convex means that the weakly-better sets are convex, it is not about the convexity of any function.